# Counter: Time from specific date until now in seconds

Tags: javascript, html, date, counter

I'm trying to make a counter that counts the time from eg. 2013 until now in seconds, and reloads every second.

So far, I've put together these code parts:

```
function+ get_uptime() {
    t1 = new Date(2013, 00, 00, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    t2 = Date.now()
    dif = t1.getTime() - t2.getTime()

    seconds = dif / 1000;
    Seconds_Between_Dates = Math.abs(seconds);
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = Seconds_Between_Dates;
    setTimeout(get_uptime, 1000);
}

get_uptime();
```

If I try to access `counter` from within an html, it fails.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/RUTVj/349/

Please do not only fix my code, but explain to me why this doesn't work.

Comment: For reference: `00` as a numeric value is the same as just `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the element has the id `seconds` but you're trying to get an element with id `counter`. Also you use the code `var t2 = Date.now()` and the javascript `Date` object does not have that static method, so you get a javascript error (visible in the console). Change this to `var t2 = new Date()` to get the current date/time.

Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/RUTVj/351/